# Compilation issues with Gradle and Realm library

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, realm

I am having getting compilation issues after adding Realm to my project. I am currently using Kotlin within Android Studio 2.1.3. This is the output from the terminal:

```
C:\Users\carre\Desktop\MBTA_99\MyApplication>gradlew build
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.                                    
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE                                        
:app:preInstantrunconfigDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkInstantrunconfigDebugManifest
:app:preInstantrunconfigReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE     
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGetkeepsafeRelinkerRelinker121Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAdsLite940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalyticsImpl940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthBase940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase940Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCastFramework940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesClearcut940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesContextmanager940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGass940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlaces940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanager940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerApi940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuth940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthCommon940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthModule940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon940Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseConfig940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCrash940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabase940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabaseConnection940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseMessaging940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorage940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorageCommon940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleMapsAndroidAndroidMapsUtils044Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareIoRealmRealmAndroidLibrary120Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareInstantrunconfigDebugDependencies
:app:compileInstantrunconfigDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileInstantrunconfigDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateInstantrunconfigDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeInstantrunconfigDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE      
:app:compileInstantrunconfigDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateInstantrunconfigDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeInstantrunconfigDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateInstantrunconfigDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateInstantrunconfigDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeInstantrunconfigDebugResources UP-TO-DATE      
:app:processInstantrunconfigDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE      
:app:processInstantrunconfigDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateInstantrunconfigDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalInstantrunconfigDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileInstantrunconfigDebugKotlin                 
e: C:\Users\carre\Desktop\MBTA_99\MyApplication\app\src\main\java\ninja\carre\mbta\activities\trainstation_list\TrainListAct.kt: (21, 12): Unresolved reference: squareup
:app:compileInstantrunconfigDebugKotlin FAILED          

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileInstantrunconfigDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 17.161 secs
```

Here's what my gradle files look like:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.3'
    ext.build_tools_version = '23.2.1'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.github.jacobono:gradle-jaxb-plugin:1.3.6'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

subprojects { project ->
    if(project.name.endsWith("-schema")) {
        apply plugin: 'com.github.jacobono.jaxb'
        dependencies {
            jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.7-b41'
            jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.7-b41'
            jaxb 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.7'
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

//    dexOptions {
//        maxProcessCount 4
//        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
//    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ninja.carre.mbta"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    productFlavors {
        instantrunconfig {
            applicationId "ninja.carre.mbta"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile(
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.8.0'],
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.8.0'],
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.8.0']
    )
    // Required -- JUnit 4 framework
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile group: 'com.google.transit', name: 'gtfs-realtime-bindings', version: '0.0.4'

    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$build_tools_version"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$build_tools_version"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$build_tools_version"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:$build_tools_version"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$build_tools_version"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$build_tools_version"
    compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2-b01'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
}
```

I started encountering this issue after adding Realm and Jackson Json parsing libraries to my project. Do you know if there's any incompatibilities between these two libraries?

EDIT 1 --- Did as you suggested and updated the build tools to the latest version and added the package classes but I am still getting an 'InstantRun' Config error. So I removed realm and its dependencies. It's still throwing a Kotlin build error. I updated the gradle script *above* respectively and left the gradle build information below.

```
C:\Users\carre\Desktop\MBTA_99\MyApplication>gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.                                                                                                                                                                                                 
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE                                        
:app:preInstantrunconfigDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkInstantrunconfigDebugManifest
:app:preInstantrunconfigReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72321Library UP-TO-DATE     
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAdsLite940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalyticsImpl940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthBase940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCastFramework940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesClearcut940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesContextmanager940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness940Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGass940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlaces940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanager940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerApi940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuth940Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthCommon940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthModule940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseConfig940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCrash940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabase940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabaseConnection940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseMessaging940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorage940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorageCommon940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleMapsAndroidAndroidMapsUtils044Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareInstantrunconfigDebugDependencies
:app:compileInstantrunconfigDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileInstantrunconfigDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateInstantrunconfigDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE      
:app:mergeInstantrunconfigDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileInstantrunconfigDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateInstantrunconfigDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeInstantrunconfigDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateInstantrunconfigDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateInstantrunconfigDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeInstantrunconfigDebugResources UP-TO-DATE      
:app:processInstantrunconfigDebugManifest                 
:app:processInstantrunconfigDebugResources                 
:app:generateInstantrunconfigDebugSources
:app:incrementalInstantrunconfigDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileInstantrunconfigDebugKotlin                 
e: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class ninja.carre.mbta.activities.train_data.prediction_by_stop.Trip, unresolved supertypes: RealmObject

:app:compileInstantrunconfigDebugKotlin FAILED          

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileInstantrunconfigDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileInstantrunconfigDebugKotlin'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:40)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:237)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more details
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile$callCompiler$10.invoke(Tasks.kt:355)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler(Tasks.kt:364)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler(Tasks.kt:148)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute(Tasks.kt:110)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:245)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:232)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 68 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 22.862 secs
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a quite specific [note in the official Realm documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#jackson-databind) that if you use jackson-databind, you'll need to create a package called `rx`, and create an empty object in it called `Observable`

```
package rx;

public class Observable {
}
```

And then it'll work.

Although your message said something about "squareup", so who knows if this is actually the problem.

As for the above workaround, they tried removing it with the Realm Optional Transformer, but it caused issues with Dexguard so the workaround remained.

EDIT: Now it just says it cannot resolve `RealmObject`

```
:app:compileInstantrunconfigDebugKotlin                 
e: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class ninja.carre.mbta.activities.train_data.prediction_by_stop.Trip, unresolved supertypes: RealmObject
```

But you can try adding the following

```
android {
    dexOptions {
        incremental false
    }
```

Along with disabling Instant Run

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your build tool version....

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
```

or download via SDK Manager.